# html before after properties not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am beginner my before element's left properties value is shows correctly in Firefox but not in correctly shows in chrome. there is 1or 2 pixel different between to browser. In this section other circle hover before image shows correctly but last circle didn't shows correctly.

CSS Code Here

```
.choose_color {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 3% 0;
}
.choose_size > h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.choose_size select {
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 1%;
}
.choose_size{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 2% 0;
}
.choose_color h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.img-for-hover1{
   display: none;
}
.img-for-hover2{
   display: none;
}
.img-for-hover3{
   display: none;
}
.img-for-hover4{
   display: none;
}
.choose_color nav ul li a{
    padding:0 3px;
}
.choose_color nav ul li a:hover .img-for-hover1 {
    bottom: 84px;
    display: block;
    left: 13px;
}
.choose_color nav ul li a:hover .img-for-hover2 {
    bottom: 84px;
    display: block;
    left: 44px;
}
.choose_color nav ul li a:hover .img-for-hover3 {
    bottom: 84px;
    display: block;
    left: 76px;
}
.choose_color nav ul li a:hover .img-for-hover4 {
    bottom: 84px;
    display: block;
    left: 108px;
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="choose_color">
                                                <h4>Choose Color</h4>
                                                <nav>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-1.png" alt="color" class="pos-relative">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-1-hover.png" alt="color" class="img-for-hover1 pos-absolute">
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-2.png" alt="color" class="pos-relative for-hide">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-2-hover.png" alt="color" class="img-for-hover2 pos-absolute">
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-3.png" alt="color" class="pos-relative">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-3-hover.png" alt="color" class="img-for-hover3 pos-absolute">
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-4.png" alt="color" class="pos-relative">
                                                                <img src="resource/img/home_img/product_details_img/color-4-hover.png" alt="color" class="img-for-hover4 pos-absolute">
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </nav>
                                            </div>
```

### Screenshots

1. [Properly working in Firefox browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GklyW.png)
2. [I face the problem in Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC5MG.png)

Comment: Share your HTML code, or provide a working example in stacksnippets, jsfiddle or what you want

Comment: Couldn't you, to keep things simple, create 2 images? One with and one without the selected icon inside of it. You could use Bootstrap Glyphicons / Google Material Icons for that. That way it can't differ between browsers / platforms.

Comment: The HTML you share was not useful. I remove all the unnecessary html.

Comment: And you don't share the correct CSS, I think you are playing with absolute positioning, and this task don't need absolute position. It's more easy than you think, but share the correct code.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need absolute positioning at all.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lzhrhrq/

---

I simplified your **HTML** and added respective classes:

```
<div class="choose_color">
  <h4>Choose Color</h4>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="selection color-black active"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="selection color-grey"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="selection color-orange"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="selection color-brown"><span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I simplified your **CSS** and added respective properties:

```
.choose_color {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 3% 0;
}
.choose_color h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.choose_color nav ul { list-style-type: none; }
.choose_color nav ul li { display: inline; }


.choose_color nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0.1;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-black:hover, .choose_color nav ul li a.color-black.active {
  border-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-grey:hover, .choose_color nav ul li a.color-grey.active {
  border-color: rgb(61,43,45);
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-orange:hover, .choose_color nav ul li a.color-orange.active {
  border-color: rgb(167,81,34);
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-brown:hover, .choose_color nav ul li a.color-brown.active {
  border-color: rgb(113,46,55);
}


.choose_color nav ul li a > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: inherit;
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-black > span {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-grey > span {
    background-color: rgb(61,43,45);
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-orange > span {
    background-color: rgb(167,81,34);
}
.choose_color nav ul li a.color-brown > span {
    background-color: rgb(113,46,55);
}
```

And for demonstration I added jQuery and this small **JS**:

```
$('nav a.selection').click( function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $('nav a.selection.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

---

*tested successfully in IE11, Chrome 50 and FF 46.*

I chose to add a `span` inside the `a` to point it out. I don't know your real markup. Maybe you use `label`s and hidden radio-buttons.
You can always remove the `span` in my example and use a pseudo-element (`::before` or `::after`) instead.

I updated the fiddle to use `label`s, `input`s (radio-buttons) and `::before`: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lzhrhrq/1/